# Magento 1.9 - Uncaught Error: Call to a member function canCapture() on boolean in

Tags: magento-1.9

Over the weekend, a product purchase seems to of triggered an error. The result of which means the orders page is displaying on the one order, with all previous orders being no longer accessible?

The following error message is displayed in the Default field of Sales / Order page.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function canCapture() on boolean in 

/home/WEBSITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Items/Abstract.php:481 Stack trace: #0
/home/WEBSITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Items/Abstract.php(176): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Items_Abstract->canEditQty() #1
/home/WEBSITE/public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/items.phtml(59): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Items_Abstract->getItemHtml(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item)) #2
/home/WEBSITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/180498.cl...') #3
/home/WEBSITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...') #4
/home/WEBSITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_ in
/home/WEBSITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Items/Abstract.php on line 481 
Product 
Item Status 
Original Price 
Price   Qty Subtotal    
VAT Amount 
VAT Percent 
Discount Amount 
Row Total
```

I'm really unsure as to what I should do to resolve this, any help would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the line `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Items/Abstract.php:481`, you will see `$this->getOrder()->getPayment()->canCapture()`.

It seems that Magento can not retrieve the payment of your order. The result of `$this->getOrder()->getPayment()` should be an object and is a boolean : that's why an exception is thrown.

You will have to debug to understand why you don't have any payment for this order.

(First step : what is the payment method assumed for this order ?)

Comment: The transaction is related to a purchase made in Australia, the customer received notification from PayPal, to which the customer had to log into PayPal to accept the conversion rate. This is nothing new, the site has performed transactions in this manner before without the above issues?